# Self-commuting of the covariant derivative: Menzel's Mathematical Physics

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Menzel defines covariant differentiation as equivalent to partial differentiation with respect to the general coordinates. “To indicate the covariant nature of the differential operator, set
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{i}}\equiv D_{i} \tag{1}$$"

He then provides the following which I have greatly abbreviated.  Consider
$$D_{i}\mathfrak{u}=D_{i}\left(\mathfrak{e}_{k}u^{k}\right)=\mathfrak{e}_{k}D_{i}u^{k}+u^{k}D_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{k}=\mathfrak{e}_{k}\frac{\partial u^{k}}{\partial q^{i}}+u^{k}D_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{k}
 \tag{2}$$.

“The operation $D_{i}u^{k}$ amounts to ordinary differentiation of the function $q^{i}$.”  But we still have $D_{i}\mathfrak{e_{j}}$ to contend with. To that end define the following:

$$D_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{j}\equiv\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\mathfrak{e}_{k} \tag{3}$$

$$\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\mathfrak{e}_{k}=\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\mathfrak{e}^{l}g_{kl}\equiv\Gamma_{ij,k}\mathfrak{e}^{k} \tag{4}$$

Dot-multiply the first of these through by $\mathfrak{e}^{k}$

$$\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{j} \tag{5}$$

Take the covariant derivative of $\delta_{\ j}^{k}$

$$D_{i}\delta_{\ j}^{k}=D_{i}(\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot\mathfrak{e}_{j})=\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{j}+\mathfrak{e}_{j}\cdot D_{i}\mathfrak{e}^{k}=0 \tag{6}$$

Therefore

$$\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=-\mathfrak{e}_{j}\cdot D_{i}\mathfrak{e}^{k} \tag{7}$$

and

$$D_{i}\mathfrak{e}^{k}=-\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\mathfrak{e}^{j} \tag{8}$$.

My reasoning to justify the relationship immediately above is that (7)
  expresses the projection of the $D_{i}\mathfrak{e}^{k}$ onto the $\mathfrak{e}_{i}$ basis. If $D_{i}\mathfrak{e}^{k}$ is replaced in (7) by the right-hand side of (8), the equivalence holds. The two sides of (8) are therefore component equivalent.

Menzel defines the covariant basis vectors as 
$$\mathfrak{e}_{i}\equiv\frac{\partial\mathfrak{r}}{\partial q^{i}}=D_{i}\mathfrak{r} \tag{9}$$

Where the $\mathfrak{r}$ is the position.

He then asserts that (7) leads to 
$$\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{i}D_{j}\mathfrak{r}=\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{j}D_{i}\mathfrak{r}=\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{j}\mathfrak{e}_{i}=\Gamma_{ji}^{k} \tag{10}$$

The gammas are therefore symmetrical on the lower indices.

I am not following his reasoning leading to (10).  What does (7) have to do with (10)?

Comment: Using the definition in (9) and equation (7), the first equality in (10) amounts to $$-\mathfrak{e}_j\cdot D_i \mathfrak{e}^k = \mathfrak{e}^k \cdot D_i \mathfrak{e}_j$$ which is just equation (6).

Comment: Looking again, I think the straightest cut is from (5): that plus equation (9) gives all but the second equality in (10), and that one follows from the commutativity of the covariant derivative with itself.

Comment: @Semiclassical The objective is to prove the commutativity of the covariant derivative.   That is what (10) is supposed to demonstrate.  I don't believe I've short-changed the reader by not providing the essential parts of Menzel's development.  Somehow $\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{i}D_{j}\mathfrak{r}=\mathfrak{e}^{k}\cdot D_{j}D_{i}\mathfrak{r}$ follows from the above, and especially from (7).

Comment: Sorry, having connectivity problems which are interfering with my ability to post.  The last comment should be:It appears Menzel was being intentionally arcane.  $\frac{\partial^{2}\mathfrak{r}}{\partial q^{j}\partial q^{k}}=\frac{\partial^{2}\mathfrak{r}}{\partial q^{k}\partial q^{j}}$ follows directly  from $\frac{\partial^{2}\mathfrak{r}}{\partial q^{j}\partial q^{k}}=\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_{i}\frac{\partial^{2}x^{i}}{\partial q^{j}\partial q^{k}}$ where $\mathfrak{x}\equiv\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_{i}x^{i}$.